# ASP.NET Identity 2 Email Confirmation Invalid Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity-2, email-confirmation

I know, this question has been asked many times in SO, but my problem is a bit different.

I'm having a odd problem with `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` and `ConfirmEmailAsync` methods.

I'm properly using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` methods before sending the email.

The odd thing is I can never reproduce any error while creating user and after getting the mail, confirming it. But in the same environment, 3 out of 10 users that signs up reports problem of Invalid Token.

I searched a bit more and I found it can happen due to Machine Key which can get changed if IIS is restarted or something or after publish. So to tackle the same, I have generated a Machine Key and kept in web.config but still the issue seems to be there.

I'm hosting this in Azure App Service.

Any more idea of what else is going wrong?

**UPDATE: I'm adding the code here for you guys to review**

```
string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

var callbackUrl = new Uri(string.Format("{0}?userId={1}&code={2}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailConfirmationURL"], user.Id, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)));

string emailTemplate = MailTemplates.UserRegistrationEmailTemplate(FirstName, CompanyName, callbackUrl);

await CustomEmail.SendEmail(new List<string> { user.Email }, "Confirm your account", emailTemplate);
```

And the confirmation works as

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(code));
```

Comment: One possible reason could be that the token is expiring before being submitted if the user takes too long to submit the token. Tokens have a lifespan within which they must be used before they are invalidated.

Comment: While you are confident that you are properly encoding the tokens. Show what you have done. May be some more eyes on the code could spot any issues.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://tech.trailmax.info/2015/05/asp-net-identity-invalid-token-for-password-reset-or-email-confirmation/ You have not mentioned security stamp for users - that can be the reason.

Comment: @trailmax Yes I have reffered to that site only to add machine.config before posting the issue here. Fortunately I have securitystamp for all the users in AspNetUsers table.

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar how did you resolve your issue, i am facing the same kind of issue, i also created thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501112/asp-net-core-email-confirmation-sometimes-says-invalidtoken, Please share your answer with us

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be that the token is expiring before being validated if the user takes too long to submit the token. Tokens have a lifespan within which they must be used before they are invalidated. The default `TokenLifespanis` one day (24hrs).

Check the identity config code to see you any change was made to the token life span.

For example the following code sets the tokens to expire in 3 hours

```
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
{
    manager.UserTokenProvider =
       new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
          (dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
          {                    
             TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
          };
}
```

With the code above, the forgotten password and the email confirmation tokens will expire in 3 hours. Users trying to use a token after the expiration will get invalid token error.

The OP indicated an inability to recreate the issue. This could be because the tokens are being validated within the token lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Url.Action` instead of creating the url using string concatenation. `Url.Action` does the encoding behind the scenes in latest MVC versions and you can avoid the encoding and decoding operations.

Below is the code snippet you can use.

```
string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

                        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new
                        {
                            userId = user.Id,
                            code = code,
                            returnUrl = model.ReturnUrl
                        }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```