# Asp.net Core Email confirmation sometimes says InvalidToken

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using asp.net core identity 2.1 and i am having a random issue with email confirmation, which while email confirmation sometimes says **result.Error = InvalidToken**. The token is also not expired.

**Note:** We are using **multiple servers**, and we have also stored our keys in one place so that all the servers use the same keys.

Code snippet for email confirmation.

**Email Confirmation**

```
var confCode = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new
        {
            userId = user.Id,
            code = WebUtility.UrlEncode(confCode)
        }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

        string confirmationEmailBody = string.Format(GetTranslatedResourceString("ConfirmationEmailBody"), "<a href='" + callbackUrl + "'>") + "</a>";
```

**Verification of token**

```
public async Task<bool> ConfirmEmailAsync(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            return false;


        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

        if (user == null)
            return false;

        var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
            result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, WebUtility.UrlDecode(code)).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return result.Succeeded;
    }
```

**Invalid Token**

The below token is encoded twice but we handle that situation

```
CfDJ8HYrrpCgcr5GvrItPOWapXRy8WF8odd%252BVKuDup7buRsl1x4agRpfgQlEIPWiBqM0Wuilu9tCv5l%252B3lNaAb89%252Fi%252B4k0y%252FH0jdXAbabz0%252FXDGA0eUrmcKdIsDFNuXeyP5ezTVmTx8t0ky9xCTXaKLAfvTsCJviETk5Ag9JbUs3l3%252BnUon6fyYOHsslJI5VKLqhMM0Sm%252BW1EE%252B%252FPEJ%252BXcn%252FPS1My%252BI1lExuF1R1hFEZScEsUCG%252Bx%252BVIFB9bzs1IoLC%252Baw%253D%253D
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: `sometimes says invalid token` means? Explain it clearly.

Comment: @TanvirArjel _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync returns invalid token in response

Comment: May be token has been expired! Have you checked this?

Comment: @TanvirArjel yes its not expiration, some users said we recieved confirmation email, and when we clicked on it, the link wasn't working. And we find out that the token was'nt valid.

Comment: Okay! Got it! I faced the similar problem! This is due to the decoding the token value when it is posting as query string. Have you got it what I am saying?

Comment: Yes, you are right, we faced this issue before, thats why we are double checking the token, first time without decoding if it fails check after decoding the token. So can you please look at above code snippet, and tell me whats wrong in it?

Comment: I already saw that but it would be better if you debug with a certain token and compare them mentally to be ensured.

Comment: @M.Tanzil did you try to change data protection configure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2 
In the previous version(i mean asp.net, not core), I have a similar problem, because the token is protected by MachineKey.Protect and i cant create on one server and use it on another. I believe its key to your problem

Comment: I had same problems, I'm using HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code).Replace("%", "-") and HttpUtility.UrlDecode(code.Replace("-", "%")), I guess same is with WebUtility.UrlEncode :)

Comment: @SilentTremor i think may be that is also our problem. but what is the reason of  replacing **% with -** ?

Comment: @M.Tanzil I don't remember exactly but if I remember correct why I did it is because of base64 alphabet where 3 characters (+, /, =) are problematic when UrlEncoded, so by doing that replacement you preserve the values after the url is opened in browser, yeah I'm not sure about it :D, should I post as answer, does it work?

Comment: @SilentTremor i haven't tried it yet, but for sure i am going to try it. i will let you know if it works. Thank you :)

Comment: Have you verified that your token are the same (with an error-example) from generating token->sending email->receiving code from link? It could be a html-error if you code contains illegal chars

Comment: @M.Tanzil, Has  you problem been solved or you need any help?

Answer (score 4):

This problem seems to be basic Query String Related issue. 
There are no pointers in your question about sample expected value and sample actual value.  Hence I will not be able to provide you exact answer here.  But below two are the pointers which will certainly resolve this issue.

There can be two issues:

**Issue 1: Original Base-64 is not restored after HtmlDecode/UrlDecode**

These tokens are encoded as base 64 strings which may contain characters like '+'.

They are sent to server.

Then server tries to perform HtmlDecode operation on this string, to remove the characters which were actually present in original base 64 token.

E.g. '+' is replaced by empty string.

So, the token generated after WebUtility.HtmlDecode is invalid.  That's why you get the invalid token error

`How to check this ?`  You can debug and see what is the value after HtmlDecode and what is expected value.  If they are differing then this is root cause.

**Issue 2: Query string not correctly formed**

Multiple key value pairs in query strings are joined using '&' character. 
e.g. key1=value1&key2=value2

But some times instead of `&` , its encoded version `&amp;` comes in the query string.
e.g. key1=value1&key2=value2

The .Net server would not be able to parse query string correctly if this is the case.

`How to check this ?`  You can use directly read raw query string from HttpContext or HttpRequest using QueryString property and check if this is the case.   If it is then you can either change your client to send appropriate query string (more logical and maintainable) or write some code to correct it on server side.

These pointers should help you to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

your request for email conformation will gives you response as userId and Your Private key but your token method should be different function like token refresh, you need to add some conditions like if token has expired then refresh  token

Comment: i think you should visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096096/asp-net-identity-email-verifcation-token-not-recognized?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect answer, but if you just need an urgent fix and less headache, just generate a shorter disaster free token/code.

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => {
        options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
        options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
    }).AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<YourDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should decode the confirmation code prior to passing it into the `_userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code).ConfigureAwait(false)` method.

You have URL encoded the confirmation code that you use in the callBackUrl; you should use `WebUtility.UrlDecode(code)` to decode it before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the user creation process is taking too much time 
Before you are clicking confirm
Make sure you check database that user is created 
Check confirm email is false in sql table

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to solve this problem using identity server.

When a user register add two column in your user table. One for verification  and others for IsVerified. In verification token column add a Guid. Then generate a link with this Guid. When a user clicks this link then you get the Guid inside a controller. Then get this user using this column, then set IsVerified column to true and delete your Guid column. And your user is now successfully verified.

Answer (score 0):

If your encoded code contains '==' in the end. i.e after urlencode or base64 encode if the code comes out like this "cm9vdA==".

decoding this will not give you the exact encoded string and will result in an invalid code.

So while generating the token check if the encoded value ends with "==". If it does generate another token and the problem will be solved.